# What is the typescript definition like for a an array of object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this javascript object:

```
subjects = {
    "1": { "id": 1, "name": "City" },
    "100": { "id": 100, "name": "Test" }
};
```

Can someone help me by telling me how I could define this in typescript. I know I can use "any" but I would like to do this properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to be able to iterate over the array using a for loop, you'd need to define length as well.

Then in theory you could define it as

`subjects : { id: number; name: string; }[] = <...>`

If you don't want to iterate over it, then you could just define it as

`subjects : { [key: string] : { id: number; name: string; } } = <...>`

Comment: - Thanks. Actually I want to iterate over it with a forEach.  I have another question on that.  Maybe you could have a quick look and then perhaps I can accept both answers if you can see what is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
subjects list:number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```

or

```
subjects list:Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could also define the contents of my object such as the id and name? Thanks

Comment: Inside the array you ask?